# Are Undefined CSS Classnames in IE7 and IE8 Expensive?

Tags: html, css, performance

If classnames are referenced in HTML but not defined in CSS, is there a performance penalty in IE7, IE8, or Firefox?

```
<div class="undefined_class">Text</div>
```

Comment: Not unless you have a ton of unused CSS selectors

Comment: ...because this increases the number of bytes that must be transferred to the client's browser.

Answer (score 4):

Ther's no particular penalty (it's just a matter of document size increasing) but a class not necessarily must be defined for styling purposes. It could be used also for DOM manipulation via javascript

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't *define* classes in CSS, you write rules that apply to that class using the CSS class selector, or `.`. You define the class for that element in the *html*.

Comment: I'd say a class in HTML is never "defined". It's just a text value assigned to an attribute. To apply styling, the browser just searches the HTML document for all selectors. If none found, move on - dont care. If found, apply styling.